# Building the tangent plane

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Truly, this should be applicable to $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I want to focus on the $\mathbb{R}^3$ case first.

Firstly, let us build a plane. Suppose we have a vector $a$ perpendicular to the plane $P$, and a point $c$ that lies on the plane. Then if point $x$ lies on the plane $P$, $\langle a,x-c \rangle = 0$, since they are perpendicular. But that also implies $\langle a,x\rangle=\langle a,c\rangle$, and $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_3 = b$, where $b = \langle a,c\rangle$.

Now, in the textbook I'm using, we have arrived at the equation of the tangent plane of $f$ at $a$, being $\langle f'(a),x-a \rangle + f(a)$. While I understood this, I want another method to construct the tangent plane, similar to what I will describe for the single variable case:

1. Let $f'(x_0)$ exist. Then, $f'(x_0)$ is an approximation of the $f$ at $x_0$, in the sense that $f'(x_0 + h) \approx f(x_0) + h\cdot f'(x_0)$.
2. Now if we define a line/hyperplane $y = f'(x_0)\cdot x$, this is an approximation to the 'change' in $f(x)$ as we 'move' from $x_0$. Note that I know better than this, but I think this is the clearest way to explain what I want to do.
3. Now shift this line/hyperplane horizontally by $x_0$ and vertically by $f(x_0)$, and we get the tangent of $f$ at $x_0$.

I want to generalize this, into the tangent hyperplanes of functions $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. This is where I get lost. In my textbook we derived that the equation of the tangent plane of $f$ at $a$ is $\langle f'(a),x-a \rangle + f(a)$, but the method used is to define a plane equation as a function of degree one, then force this function to be equal to the linear function that approximates $f$. While I can understand this just fine, I would like a geometric approach like I described for the single variable case.

Let $f'(a)$ exists. Then, it's partial derivatives $Df_1(a),Df_2(a)$ exist. Then, we have 2 lines tangent to $f(a)$, with slopes $Df_1(a),Df_2(a)$ (in the 2-d plane section). I'm not sure how to describe these lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ though, maybe I need to create a parameterization?

I do not how to complete my construction of the plane, unlike the single-variable case.

Furthermore, like I said at the beginning, the vector $a$ should be tangent to all vectors that line on the plane, $\langle a,x-c \rangle = 0$. With the tangent plane, we know that the vector $a$ is actually $f'(a)$. But that means the gradient is perpendicular to the tangent plane? I'm really confusing myself

Comment: When you write, "the equation of the tangent plane of $f$ at $a$, being $\langle f'(a), x - a\rangle$", that's a description of the tangent plane to a _level set_ of $f$, and $f'(a)$ represents the _gradient vector_ of $f$ at $a$. <> Later, however, it sounds as if you want the tangent plane to the _graph_ of $f$, with $f'(a)$ denoting the _derivative matrix_ of $f$ at $a$. These are not the same data, nor do they address exactly the same question. (Not sure I understand what's being asked, hence the comment instead of an answer.)